# Testing Grpc Services Written in Multiple Languages

Tags: go, testing, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-go

So I have a fairly complex distributed system composed of multiple services (Service 1, Service 2, Service 3, and Service 4). Each one of these services is a grpc server and they often communicate with each other (e.g. Service 1 will make a rpc to Service 2 that will return a response, or Service 1 makes a rpc to Service 3 that makes another rpc to Service 4 before returning a response to Service 1). The tricky part is that these services are written in different programming languages, some of them are in Python and some of them are in Go.

How can I write tests for the rpc endpoints in each server if they are written in different languages, and what do I do for the rpc endpoints that need to contact another one of the services before returning a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to test each of these services independently using mocks.

For a service written in go you can use gomocks, please refer this link:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/golang/mock&ved=2ahUKEwi6nu2rquzpAhVNwjgGHcxiAekQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3EoV6CtCn21kcU-Q4bneys

So if you need to test service 1 which has calls to service 2, you mock the service 2 to return the expected result. You should be able to find similar mocking frameworks for other languages as well

Comment: But what if service 1 is in Go and service 2 is in python? How do I mock service 2 to be interoperable with my go tests for service 1?

Comment: @MUAS How are the services wired? Through REST, gRPC? And also what are you trying to test exactly? Is it the working of all the services as a whole or individual services separately?

Comment: They are wired through gRPC. I wanted to test the individual services separately, but the problem is that some services call onto other services, so to test them separately I would have to mock the service that gets called.

Comment: Since you are using grpc what language you are using should not be a problem. The .pb file will have both the client and server stubs. So if the service 2 is in python, gomock would generate the stub with all the necessary methods needed to call service 2. Gomock uses the server stubs from .pb file to generate mocks. Please go through the gomock documentation